# How to pass v-model to child component with change event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue2 project and I am using Vuetify. I am trying to make filters that hide some games when certain filter is turned off.

Everything is working as it should until I try to make it a separate component.

I am trying to make these filters work as a child component.

**Parent component**

```
 <game-providers
   :allGamesSum="allGamesSum"
   :vendorList="vendorList"
    v-model="model"
    @set-provider-filter="setProviderFilter"
    @set-all-provider-filter="setAllProviderFilter"
 ></game-providers>
```

**V-model data**

```
model: {
        allPset: 0,
        vendorFilter: [],
      },
```

**Child component**

```
<v-sheet elevation="1" height="100%" outlined rounded width="100%">
    <h3 style="margin: 10px">Game providers</h3>
    <v-btn-toggle
      :value="value.allPset"
      block
      @change="$emit('set-all-provider-filter')"
      style="display: block"
    >
      <v-btn block dark style="margin-top: 10px">
        All providers
        <v-spacer />
        <v-chip>{{ allGamesSum }}</v-chip>
      </v-btn>
    </v-btn-toggle>
    <v-btn-toggle
      :value="value.vendorFilter"
      @change="$emit('set-provider-filter')"
      block
      multiple
      style="display: block"
    >
      <v-btn
        v-for="(item, i) in vendorList"
        :key="i"
        :value="item.name"
        height="30px"
        block
        dark
        style="margin-top: 1px"
        ><img style="background-color: transparent" :src="item.src" />
        <v-spacer />
        <v-chip small>{{ item.gameSum }}</v-chip>
      </v-btn>
    </v-btn-toggle>
  </v-sheet>
```

**Props**

```
props: ['value', 'vendorList', 'allGamesSum'],
```

I have two functions that I emit that should work on `@change` as shown in the first paragraph. I have no idea what I need to do more to make it work as a separate component.

`v-btn-toggle` has change event and value property.

Every help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do not use @chenge  in v-btn you need use @click

this is the answer:

**Child component**

```
<v-sheet elevation="1" height="100%" outlined rounded width="100%">
<h3 style="margin: 10px">Game providers</h3>
<v-btn-toggle
  :value="value.allPset"
  block
  @click="$emit('set-all-provider-filter')"
  style="display: block"
>
  <v-btn block dark style="margin-top: 10px">
    All providers
    <v-spacer />
    <v-chip>{{ vallGamesSum }}</v-chip>
  </v-btn>
</v-btn-toggle>
<v-btn-toggle
  :value="value.vendorFilter"
  @click="$emit('set-provider-filter')"
  block
  multiple
  style="display: block"
>
  <v-btn
    v-for="(item, i) in vendorList"
    :key="i"
    :value="item.name"
    height="30px"
    block
    dark
    style="margin-top: 1px"
    ><img style="background-color: transparent" :src="item.src" />
    <v-spacer />
    <v-chip small>{{ item.gameSum }}</v-chip>
  </v-btn>
</v-btn-toggle>
```

Comment: Not working. ````v-btn-toggle```` doesn't contain change event + we need to $emit some kind of value but I don't know what exactly.